# RadioListTile not update

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class SelectBell extends StatefulWidget {
  SelectBell({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SelectBell> createState() => _SelectBellState();
}

class _SelectBellState extends State<SelectBell> {
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
  Bell? selectedBell;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadBells();
  }

  void loadBells() async {

      DB().getBells().then(
            (bells) {
          for (Bell bell in bells) {
            setState(() {
              if(selectedBell == null){
                selectedBell = bell;
              };
              widgets.add(RadioListTile(
                  title: Text(bell.name),
                  value: bell,
                  groupValue: selectedBell,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    print(selectedBell!.name);
                    setState(() {
                      selectedBell = value!;
                    });
                    print(selectedBell!.name);
                  },
                   selected: selectedBell == bell
              ));
            });
          }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            width: 250,
            child: Column(
              children: widgets,
            )));
  }
}
```

So here is my problem, the radiobutton state is not updating when tapped. When I open the dialog it does show that my selection to first item is working (1), but it doesn't change to selected when tapped. The prints does return true and selectedBell value has the right value.

Comment: "When I open the dialog it does show that" - please show the code for the dialog. also, please [edit] your question to make the code runnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not store references to `Widget`s as you're doing with your `widgets` field.
Instead, store references to objects that will be constructed *inside* the `build` method.

Also, you're calling `setState` a lot of times inside your `initState` method, when it should be called only once: when the data is loaded:

```dart
class SelectBell extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectBell({super.key});

  @override
  State<SelectBell> createState() => _SelectBellState();
}

class _SelectBellState extends State<SelectBell> {
  // If `bells` is null, it's not loaded from `DB` yet
  List<Bell>? bells;
  Bell? selectedBell;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadBells();
  }

  void loadBells() async {
    final List<Bell> bells = await DB().getBells();
    setState(() {
      this.bells = bells;
      selectedBell ??= bells[0];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Bell> bells = this.bells ?? [];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        width: 250,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for (Bell bell in bells)
              RadioListTile<Bell>(
                title: Text(bell.name),
                value: bell,
                groupValue: selectedBell,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print(selectedBell!.name);
                  setState(() {
                    selectedBell = value!;
                  });
                  print(selectedBell!.name);
                },
                selected: selectedBell == bell,
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Really works. I don't fully understand what the problem was, but I will figure it out.